# Creating a slideshow with images and text overlays

Tags: 7, media, wysiwyg

Does anyone know of a module or method to create a node where users can upload an image, add text on top of it through a WYSIWYG, then have the image combined with the text (merge the text and image into one jpg/png)?

We are trying to find a way for users in a school to add slides to our digital signage without using powerpoint, and I was wondering if there was a Drupal module that could do the job or help make it easier.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that there's a module that supports the dynamic placing of text on top of an image in a wysiwyg editor. However, you should be able to use the [imagecache_actions](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) module to superimpose a text field onto an image field; IOW, you'd need to have separate fields (or a [field collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection)) for the image and text. It also supports custom actions which should allow you to exploit the imageapi and GD as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you're displaying slides on your website, you don't have to merge the text with the jpg/png. You can create a js slideshow with images and texts over them using CSS. You can use [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow/) for that. Basically, it can create js slideshows using Views. Sou you can create a content type with a body and an image field, create a view to display the nodes for your content type and display them using Views Slideshow.